# Escaping double quotes in a variable in a shell script

Tags: macos, shell, unix, terminal

hopefully a simple question and the last piece in my puzzle... :-) I have a shell script running in terminal under os x. It contains among other things:

```
name=$(basename "$file")
printf "%s" "\"$name\";"
```

... which is fine ... but lets say that the file name contains a double quote - IMA"G09%'27.jpg - then the output would be:

"IMA"G09%'27.jpg;"

... and that would "break" my line intended for putting into a db later (the double quote). So I need to escape it so I get the output:

"IMA\"G09%'27.jpg;"

... but I couldn't figure out how ... anyone? :-)

EDIT - RESULT: With the help of anubhava this is what I use (to get file info incl. type/creator):

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type f -name '*' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
    name=$(basename "$file")
    path=$(dirname "$file")
    # full_path=$(readlink -f "$file") # This only works on Linux
    full_path=$(echo "$PWD/${file#./}")
    extension=${name##*.}
    size_human_readable=$(ls -lh "$file" | awk -F' ' '{print $5}')
    size_in_bytes=$(stat -f "%z" "$file")
    creation_date=$(stat -f "%SB" "$file")
    last_access=$(stat -f "%Sa" "$file")
    last_modification=$(stat -f "%Sm" "$file")
    last_change=$(stat -f "%Sc" "$file")
    creator=$(mdls -name kMDItemFSCreatorCode "$file")


    printf "\"%q\";" "$name"
    printf "%s" "\"$full_path\";"
    printf "%s" "\"$extension\";"
    printf "\"$size_human_readable\";"
    printf "\"$size_in_bytes\";"
    printf "\"$last_modification\";"
    printf "%s" "\"$creator\""
    printf "\n"
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `printf` with `%q`:

```
name='file"naeme.txt'

printf "\"%q;\"" "$name"
"file\"naeme.txt;"
```

Comment: changed printf "%s" "\"$name\";" to printf "%s\"%q;\"" "\"$name\";" ... but still getting the same output, ie. "file"name.txt;" ... because I combine it with "%s" ? But I need that, otherwise files with names containing % is skipped.

Comment: You need to provide more examples in your question where `%q` doesn't work for you.

Comment: Hmm, you are right, works with % ... BUT ... I need my double quotes around the whole string unescaped, and those are now also getting escaped:     printf "\"%q;\"" "\"$name\";" gives me "\"IMA\"G09%\'27.jpg\"\;

Comment: ahh but the I could do the printf in 3 steps, ofcourse! Thanks, got it - will post the final result a bit later :-) Thanks for the help!! :-)

Comment: Try this command: `s="IMA\"G09%'27.jpg" && printf "\"%q;\"" "$s"`. It gives me: **`"IMA\"G09%\'27.jpg;"`** As you can see outer quotes are unescaped.

Comment: One thing though ... strangely, when using %q; ... it also messes up the encoding a bit. Fx. local danisk chars, æøå, are messed up + other issues. Using it, will do a search/replace later on all of it (expecting 1.000.000+ lines). Do you know why?

Comment: without the %q; .... "4020565 Intern låneseddel.qxd";"/volumes/Bording/Agetor arkiv/Københavns Universitet/4020565/4020565 Intern låneseddel.qxd";"qxd";"130K";"133120";"Jul  2 09:24:20 2014";"kMDItemFSCreatorCode = """

Comment: with the %q; .... "$'4020565 Intern laÃ\212neseddel.qxd'";"$'/volumes/Bording/Agetor arkiv/K√∏benhavns Universitet/4020565/4020565 Intern laÃ\212neseddel.qxd'";"qxd";"130K";"133120";"Jul  2 09:24:20 2014";"kMDItemFSCreatorCode = """

Comment: You have told anywhere that you're dealing with non-ASCII characters also. As for `%q` is concerned it is `%q - quote the argument in a way that can be reused as shell input` So in theory it should work as long as your file is correctly encoded and your terminal supports it. Having said that I think it would be better if you create a new question for handling unicode characters with a link to this question.

Comment: The problem you're running into is that `%q` quotes/escapes a string suitably for interpretation by bash, and may use any of a number of quote/escape styles that bash supports -- but whatever you're actually feeding this to only understands some of those styles. Hence... inconsistent results.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach, using `sed` to control the escaping:

```
printquoted() {
    printf '"%s";' "$(LC_ALL=C sed 's/["]/\\&/g' <<<"$1")"
}

printquoted "$name"
printquoted "$full_path"
printquoted "$extension"
...etc
```

If it turns out there are other things you need to escape besides double-quotes (like, say, backslashes themselves), you can add them to the `sed` `[]` expression (e.g. `["\]` would escape double-quotes and backslashes).

Note that this approach will fail horribly if the string contains any newlines (which is legal in filenames).